# About: blank when switching window in selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The task is to click on the element, go to a new window and get the url of the new window. But instead of url "about: blank" is displayed. How to fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\SeleFire\geckodriver.exe')
url = driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/windows/new"]'))).click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible problems here:

1. Wait for element visibility, not just presence
2. Small sleep after the click

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\SeleFire\geckodriver.exe')
url = driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/windows/new"]'))).click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried it, the code works as long as it contains sleep. That is why I ask, is there an alternative to it? 

PS: Voted for the answer. Due to low reputation my vote is not accepted.

Comment: I don't know. I could do it with Java or C#, but I can't see expected conditions validating url content in Python